# Benchmarking multiple instances

Tags: pallet, weight, benchmarking, instantiable

We have two instances of a pallet with different runtime configurations. How can we run the benchmarks separately to generate two distinct sets of weights?

As far as I can tell this is not possible and if you list multiple pallet instances (such as in the `kusama runtime` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/dc230b323b5baeb9b4297430ed539b208d30bf6a/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L1556-L1557)) it will use the last instance.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You just run the benchmark like for any other pallet.
The output will list the calls multiple times and finally print:

```
Created file: "runtime/kusama/src/weights/pallet_referenda_fellowship_referenda.rs"
Created file: "runtime/kusama/src/weights/pallet_referenda_referenda.rs"
```

Be sure to specify a **folder** and not a **file** path for the `--output` like in [Kusama](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/dc230b323b5baeb9b4297430ed539b208d30bf6a/runtime/kusama/src/weights/pallet_referenda_fellowship_referenda.rs#L36).
Otherwise it will overwrite the same file and print this as last line:

```
Created file: "runtime/kusama/src/weights/pallet_referenda.rs"
Created file: "runtime/kusama/src/weights/pallet_referenda.rs"
Multiple benchmarks were written to the same file: "runtime/kusama/src/weights/pallet_referenda.rs".
```